# Databases are not getting displayed in SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I'm stuck with a strange problem.

I tried to restore a database snapshot to a database. Usually it doesn't take much time to restore, but now it took 5 minutes and is still restoring, so I stopped query execution. It was trying to stop the query execution for more that 5 minutes, so i closed SSMS using task manager.

Then I tried to kill the restore process using `KILL`.

[image]

Now I am able to can connect to that server, but the list of databases is not opening. I mean: whoever is connected to this server, they are not able to get the databases. When I checked the `sysprocesses` table, it is showing `lastwaittype` as `LCK_M_S`.

None of my users can see databases. Looks like I kind of messed up. I cannot restart SQL Server as others are connected to the server.

How do I solve this? Please help.

**EDIT:**
i tried [this approach](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/02/15/sql-server-lck_m_xxx-wait-type-day-15-of-28/) and when i checked with

```
select db_name(dbid), * from sysprocesses where blocked <> 0
```

i got two records,

[image]

do you think because of these two rest of the process are getting locked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there still is some hidden lock on the `sysdatabases` table in the master database. This could very well be caused by the `KILL` of the restore command.

The article here might help you:

http://ellisweb.net/2012/02/clearing-out-a-mysterious-table-lock-lck_m_s-in-sql-server-2008/

It basically advises you to identify where the hidden lock is coming from, and then issuing  a `KILL` on that process ID.

Comment: are you sure? coz that approach says "its a dirty way and must utilize this only if you are confident.".. im not that confident, coz others are using this server.

Comment: by kill 13, will it corrupt the sql server or the database or both ?

Comment: How about checking sys.dm_tran_locks for some additonal info?

Comment: It actually looks as if both processes in the second screenshot are blocked by process 69, which you already tried to kill.

Comment: SchmitzIT,can we continue over chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18576/discussion-between-harsha-and-schmitzit

Comment: sql server could not be restarted, so the system was restarted.. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the instance.  Can't hurt if your users can't see any of the databases anyway.

Comment: yes, the users cannot see the list of database but they can connect the databases from a new query window or a .net application.